# Javascript split String in different pieces and return as array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, regex, string

i kind of have a problem to filter out my string, cant figure out a simple way todo that,

i would love to split my string into and array where the words surrounded with {{WORD}},
get into one array piece and the string without into another,

lets say i have this string here:

{{participant_name}} picked {{picked_skills}} skills this round!

would love to split it into an array as following:

```
array[0]: {{participant_name}}
array[1]: picked
array[2]: {{picked_skills}}
array[3]:  skills this round!
```

would appreciate all help i can get

Comment: What's the expected output if this was the input string: `{{a}} b c {{d}} e f g {{h}} {{i}} {{j}} k l m n o {{p}}`?

Comment: so the expected output would be an array as following: array[0]: {{a}}, array[1]: b , array[2]: c, array[3]: {{d}} and so on ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const regexQuery = /{{(.+)}} (.+) {{(.+)}} (.+)/g
const arr = regexQuery.exec('{{participant_name}} picked {{picked_skills}} skills this round!')
arr.shift()
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the string changes to `{{participant_name}} picked up {{picked_skills}} skills this round!`

According to OP's response to my question earlier, the result should include the word "up" in a separate array element. But doing that makes the regex not match.

Comment: @Jon I was assuming that the 2nd variable is always a single word, but here you go, updated.